# Wrong import of waxeye parser

Tags: python, python-2.7, parser-generator, waxeye

So I tried to use parses generator [waxeye](http://waxeye.org/), but as I try to use tutorial example of program in python using generated parser I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Parser'
```

Here's part of code its reference to:

```
import waxeye
import parser

p = parser.Parser()
```

The last line cause the error. Parser generated by waxeye I put in the same directory as the **init**.py . It's parser.py .

Anyone have any idea what's wrong with my code?

---

**Edit 20-05-2013:**

Beggining of the parser.py file:

```
from waxeye import Edge, State, FA, WaxeyeParser

class Parser (WaxeyeParser):
```

Comment: It might be that the `parser` you're importing is not the one you want. Try inserting a `print parser.__file__` right after the imports, or try naming your parser module differently. Also, if working with Python 2.7 its good to enable `absolute_imports` from the `__future__` module.

Comment: Ok! So `print parser.__file__` is giving almost the same error : `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`.
Changing the name of parser actually work. Thanks! If you give it as an answer - I'll accept it in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the `parser` module you're importing is not the one you want.

Try inserting a:

```
print parser.__file__
```

right after the imports, or try naming your parser module differently.

Also, if working with Python 2.7 its good to enable `absolute_imports` from the `__future__` module.

Answer (score 1):

Python already has a module named parser. The import statement will load system parser module instead of local parser.py file. The simplest way to fix this issue is to change the filename of parser.py. For example, xxparser.py.

```
import waxeye
import xxparser

p = xxparser.Parser()
```